# If I made a local copy of an open source project to work on, how do I merge new changes from the developers into my code?

Tags: git

I created an empty repository in bitbucket, and cloned it into the directory `dwm`. Then I pulled in dwm's code from suckless.org and updated my custom repo with it:

```
git pull http://git.suckless.org/dwm
git push -u origin master --tags
```

I made a few changes, and now I want to prepare for when suckless.org makes other commits; I want to merge their changes with my commits. Will this work?

```
git checkout -b new
git fetch http://git.suckless.org/dwm
git checkout master
git merge new
git branch -d merge
```

I just created the repository and downloaded the most recent version today, so there haven't been any new commits from suckless.org to test this with, but I'm hoping to be proactive and figure it out a head of time. Will this procedure work? For example, if I've modified `dwm.c` and the developers have also made changes, git should pick up on the differences and perform the merge?

I don't want to push my changes back to the open source project; I'm just modifying a copy of the project for use on my machine, and storing that local copy and its commits (along with those of the developers) in a bitbucket repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pull those changes into your `new` branch, then I would recommend doing this instead:

```
git remote add suckless http://git.suckless.org/dwm
```

Adds a remote for future reference so you don't have to keep typing out that URL.

```
git checkout -b new
git pull suckless master
```

Creates a new branch called `new` and switch to it. You don't need the `-b` option if this branch already exists. Pull in the changes from the `suckless master` branch and add them to this branch.

The `fetch` command only fetches the latest updates from the remote repository and will not apply them. You need to `pull` those changes to apply them.

```
git checkout master
git merge new
```

Switches back to the master branch and merges the `new` branch into the `master` branch.

```
git branch -d new
```

Delete the `new` branch now that you don't need it.